# JavaScript function - Looping through a string, styling individual characters

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to pass a number string through a function that iterates through each character, wrapping each in a  element if it is or is not a number.

```
var str = "$6,117,766.69";
var nonNumber = "$,.";

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (nonNumber.contains(str[i])) {
        $('body').append("<span class = 'thecolorYellow'>"+str[i]+"</span>");
    } else {
        $('body').append("<span class = 'thecolorBlue'>"+str[i]+"</span>");
    } 
}
```

My question is this: How can I make this a function that returns this as a string instead of modifying the DOM? And second, how could I adapt this function to make sure that characters outside of 0-9 and the three non-numerics are omitted from the final string?

Comment: You want your function to return a string of HTML? Given the `str` variable in your code, precisely what output do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use `replace` to generate the markup, then you can append it all at once:

```
var html = str.replace(/./g, function(match) {
  var clas = isNaN(match) ? 'yellow' : 'blue'
  return '<span class="'+ clas +'">'+ match +'</span>'
})

$('body').append(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function getAmountAsNumber(dollarAmount)
    {
     return dollarAmount.replace(/\D/g,'');

    }
```

The above function will return just the digits 0-9 from your input string and will also make sure that all your non-numeric characters are ommitted.